# Relación muchos a muchos no funciona en los dos sentidos

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

Por algún motivo la relacion muchos a muchos no me funciona en los dos sentidos, tengo la tabla `products` que tiene muchos `properties` y viceversa.

las migraciones:

```
/*products table*/
class CreateProductsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('category_id')
                  ->references('id')->on('categories')
                  ->onDelete('restrict')
                  ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
    }
}

/******************************/
/*properties table            */
/******************************/
class CreatePropertiesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('properties', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

/******************************/
/*pivot table                 */
/******************************/
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('product_property', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('content')->nullable();

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('property_id');

        $table->foreign('product_id')
              ->references('id')->on('products')
            //   ->onDelete('cascade')
              ->onUpdate('cascade');

        $table->foreign('property_id')
              ->references('id')->on('properties')
            //   ->onDelete('cascade')
              ->onUpdate('cascade');

        $table->unique(['product_id', 'property_id']);
    });
}
```

El modelo de `product` es este.
Si os fijais también he probado a indicarle manualmente la tabla pivote pero tampoco funciona.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'category_id',
        'name',
        'price',
        'coin',
        'rrp',
    ];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }

    public function wishlists()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Wishlist');
    }

    public function properties()
    {
        // return $this->belongsToMany('App\Property', 'product_property', 'product_id', 'property_id');
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Property');
    }
}
```

y finalmente el modelo `property`

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Property extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'properties';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
    }
}
```

Este comando funciona perfectamente `Property::find(1)->products`.

Mientras que este me retorna una colección vacia. `Product::find(1)->properties`

Por si vale de algo en el controlador los datos se meten mediante `sync`  y funciona `$product->properties()->sync($properties_id);` donde `properties_id` es un array

he comprobodado si las relaciones existen y me dice que no
     `$product->find(1)->properties()->exists()`

mientras que en `category` por supuesto me dice que existe
     `$category->find(1)->products()->exists()`

para terminar de comprobar he probado ha hacer la consulta en sql y funciona perfectamente

```
SELECT properties.* 
FROM products,properties,product_property 
WHERE products.id = product_property.product_id AND
      properties.id = product_property.property_id AND 
      products.id = 8
```

No se que es lo que se me escapa, porque los datos existen.
¿Algún problema de caché?

Answer (score 0):

Deberías colocar la tabla pivot en ambos modelos y verifica bien tus datos almacenados.

En el modelo Product:

```
public function properties()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Property', 'product_property');
}
```

En el modelo Property:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'product_property');
}
```

Comment: No funciona, he comprobado si las relaciones existen `$product->find(1)->properties()->exists()` y me dice que no.

Comment: ¿Realmente necesitas el unique de la tabla pivot? `$table->unique(['product_id', 'property_id']);`. Porque de ser así entonces no tiene razón de ser la tabla pivot y sería preferible colocar un hasOne como relación.

Comment: Diria que si. Lo utilizo para que un producto no repita la misma propiedad.
La relación es que un propucto tiene 1 o más propiedades distintas y cada propiedad puede estar en 1 o más productos.